# Ayuda con Operaciones de suma, diferencia y calculo automatico con javascript php html5

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, pdo

> Hola amigos buen día, soy nuevo en desarrollo y estoy desarrollando un formulario con php, mysql(pdo), bootsrtap, javascript, tengo un problema quiero que al seleccionar algunos elementos input del tipo select sus valores realicen operaciones de calculo como suma y resta, pero desconozco de la definicion de una funcion en javascript que ayudaria realizarlo automaticamente, quiero que realice lo siguiente el siguiente formulario, cada vez que seleccione el elemento select del precio, vaya calculando la suma es decir:
>
> Total_Pagar = Precio_Montura + Precio_TipoLuna - Descuento(puede ir con valor como no tambien es opcional) y que posteriormente se agregue un valor a Acuenta(amortizacion del total a pagar en en caso no cuenta con todo el dinero) y luego que calcule el saldo es decir: Saldo = Total_a_Pagar - Acuenta ; todo esto quiero que se calcule automaticamente ya que posteriormente lo voy a enviar algunos de los datos a la base de datos.
>
> Tambien quisiera saber como podria a parte de esto ir decrementando el stock de  una tabla que se llama montura,utilizando un metodo en mysql con pdo o mysqli, cuando guarde esta funcionalidad de generacion de una venta en una base de datos, asi esta definido mi tabla que tiene como nombre = Montura (id_montura,marca,nombre,precio_venta,cantidad).
>
> Agradezco su ayuda, saludos cordiales, estare atento a su ayuda. Se que no es una buena practica hacer esta defincion con la tabla venta, pero en vista que las reglas del negocio, lo ameritan creo que he tenido que definir de esta forma. Agradezco sus sugerencias y recomendaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nomb_montura">SELECCIONAR MONTURA</label>
      <select name="nomb_montura" id="nomb_montura" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="MONTURA 1">MONTURA 1</option>
        <option value="MONTURA 2">MONTURA 2</option>
        <option value="MONTURA 3">MONTURA 3</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="precvent_montura">PRECIO (S/.)</label>
      <select name="precvent_montura" id="precvent_montura" class="form-control" required keypress="calcularTotalVenta();">
        <option value="120">100</option>
        <option value="200">200</option>
        <option value="300">300</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nomb_tipoluna">SELECCIONAR TIPO DE LUNA</label>
      <select name="nomb_tipoluna" id="nomb_tipoluna" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="LUNA 1">LUNA 1</option>
        <option value="LUNA 2">LUNA 2</option>
        <option value="LUNA 3">LUNA 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="precvent_tipoluna">PRECIO (S/.)</label>
      <select name="precvent_tipoluna" id="precvent_tipoluna" class="form-control" required keypress="calcularTotalVenta();">
        <option value="70">70</option>
        <option value="85">85</option>
        <option value="90">90</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="descuento">DESCUENTO (S/.)</label>
      <input type="number" name="descuento" id="desc" value="0.00" step="0.01" min="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control" keypress="calcularTotalVenta();">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="total_pagar">TOTAL A PAGAR (S/.)</label>
      <input type="text" id="total_pagar" name="total_pagar" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="acuenta">ACUENTA (S/.)</label>
      <input type="number" name="acuenta" id="acuenta" class="form-control" step="0.01" min="0.00" placeholder="0.00">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="saldo">SALDO (S/.)</label>
      <input type="number" name="saldo" id="saldo" class="form-control" step="0.01" min="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ya le di formato mi estimado, espero que ya se pueda dar a entender mi consulta, muchas gracias.

Comment: Amigo, estas preguntando sobre PHP, javascript y HTML5, pero lo unico que veo en tu codigo es HTML5 y MySQL, que haz intentado del lado del frontend (javascript)?, no veo evidencia ni tampoco muestras en la pregunta aquello que haz intentado en javascript. A fin de cuentas la propia pregunta se resuelve principalmente mediante javascript, si tu respuesta es que muestras lo demas porque no tienes codigo javascript ya que no sabes como podrias hacerlo en javascript entonces preguntaste en un mal momento, ya que nosotros resolvemos dudas sobre codigo que tengas, mas `NO` generamos codigo.

Comment: Ademas que eso que pusiste como codigo es solo `HTML`, html es la estructura en si,  por lo tanto no tiene funcionalidad alguna ni puede realizar aquello que intentas.

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo lo que comentas podrías hacer que cada que cambie el select se ejecute una función que realice los cálculos que necesitas y los coloque en los inputs que tienes de total, algo tipo:

```
<select name="nomb_tipoluna" id="nomb_tipoluna" class="form-control" required onchange="realizarCalculo(this)">
        <option value="LUNA 1">LUNA 1</option>
        <option value="LUNA 2">LUNA 2</option>
        <option value="LUNA 3">LUNA 3</option>
      </select>

<script>
realizarCalculo(opcionElegida) {
    //Aquí realizas tus cálculos

    //Luego tomas los id de los input con getElementById o cualquier otro selector que prefieras

   //Imprimes los datos en los inputs modificandole su value
}
 </script>
```